# Book about two kids who travel back in time and meet a dinosaur that likes gingko fruit

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, dinosaurs

I read the book a long time ago as a child. If I remember correctly, it was about two kids who found a cave along the shore with dinosaur footprints, and when they followed the footprints into the cave, they would emerge in the era of the dinosaurs. They also met a friendly dinosaur who liked to eat gingko fruits. I think it was part of a series.

Comment: Talk about bad breath...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Attack of the Tyrannosaurus by Rex Stone](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wlmmOwAACAAJ).

[image: Attack of the Tyrannosaurus]

The Google Books summary says:

> Tom and Jamie can't believe their luck when they find a secret entrance to a prehistoric world filled with dinosaurs!
>   The first dinosaur they meet is a friendly wannanosaurus. It eats the fruit from super-stinky ginkgo trees. But soon, Tom and Jamie meet a much less friendly dino: a Tyrannosaurus Rex that would like to eat them!

Comment: ^_^ Yours has more detail than mine. Good work!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks, I think we must have posted within seconds of each other. This story identification is getting mighty competitive :-)